# ST_MakePoint returns an error when using Python

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2, pandas

I am trying to use `ST_Point` or `ST_MakePoint` to create points from a table of latitude and longitudes coordinates. However I am consistently getting an error even when trying the [examples](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html).

For example

```
pd.read_sql("SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),4326)", my_db_connection)
```

returns an error

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
SELECT ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829)
': function st_makepoint(numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems that this has to do with how the query is being passed from Python (I've tried using `pandas` and `psycopg2` but no luck) but I am not sure why this would matter when I am trying to run my query using real data (`SELECT ST_Point(lon, lat) FROM my_table`).

Casting doesn't seem to help either. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Are you sure postgis extension is installed in your database?

Comment: Yes. Other postgis commands work fine.

Comment: You say *casting doesn't seem to help either*. What did you cast it to? double precision?

Comment: @zimmi yeah I tried double precision/float/numeric but same result. Currently trying to do something using `ST_GeomFromText` and concating my coords with some strings but not having much luck.

Comment: Does it work with raw SQL, e.g. without using python?

Comment: You need to add the exact version of tools used when asking a question like that.

Comment: Take a look at the log of the postgresql server. There you will see how the query is received from python to PostGIS.

Comment: From Python, add the return from `SELECT postgis_full_version()` to your question.